# How to handle nested collection in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a collection of models. Some of these models might contain a nested collection of the same models. In my JSON this is set up as an array. The issue I was getting was that it was remaining as an array and not getting parsed into the collection of models I wanted it to be. This was a problem because I was navigating through the data recursively and I wanted to be able to treat each model as a Backbone model and not just a plain old object.
I am calling collection of model , within same model .
Initialize function:-

```
function(response) {

       if (response.filters) {
             this.set('filters', new FilterCollection(response.filters));
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are trying to convert the array to a proper collection in `initialize`. That's not the ideal place. Assuming you load your data from the server with `fetch`, the conversion needs to happen [in `parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) instead.

The `parse` method is also the right choice if you pass the attributes to the constructor while creating the model. The attributes will be processed with `parse` [by setting the option `{parse: true}`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor). You don't need additional code in `initialize` for that. The [example in the Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) illustrates the very thing you are trying to do.